# Laravel - Response:: or response() - which one is better

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-facade

I was just curious about Facade and service container binding functions in Laravel 5.1, let's say `Reponse::json()` and `response()->json()` are the same. But is there any reason that one of them is better than the other?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is already stated on the Laravel's documentation

> Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in
>   the application's service container. Laravel ships with many facades,
>   and you have probably been using them without even knowing it! Laravel
>   "facades" serve as "static proxies" to underlying classes in the
>   service container, **providing the benefit of a terse, expressive syntax**
>   **while maintaining more testability and flexibility than traditional**
>   **static methods.**

And [this article](http://taylorotwell.com/response-dont-use-facades/) by the creator of Laravel will also help you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as posed by @DucCuong